# Libgdx: screen resize and ClickListener (libgdx)

Tags: libgdx

I develope a 2D game and use OrthographicCamera and Viewport to resize virtaul board to real display size. I add images to stage and use ClickListener to detect clicks. It works fine, but when I change resolution it works incorrent(can't detect correct actor, I think the problem with new and original x and y). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to translate the screen coordinates to world coordinates.
Your camera can do that. You can do both ways, `cam.project(...)` and `cam.unproject(...)`

Or if you are already using Actors, don't initialize a camera yourself, but use a `Stage`. Create a Stage and add the actors to it. The Stage will then do coordinate translation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Once me too suffered from this problem but at end i got the working solution, for drawing anything using SpriteBatch or Stage in libgdx. Using orthogrphic camera we can do this.

first choose one constant resolution which is best for game. Here i have taken 1280*720(landscape).

```js
class ScreenTest implements Screen{
 
final float appWidth = 1280, screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
final float appHeight = 720, screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

OrthographicCamera camera;

SpriteBatch batch;
Stage stage;

Texture img1;
Image img2;

 public ScreenTest(){
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
  camera.setToOrtho(false, appWidth, appHeight);
   
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
   batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
     
        img1 = new Texture("your_image1.png");
   img2 = new Image(new Texture("your_image2.png"));
   img2.setPosition(0, 0); // drawing from (0,0)
  
        stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(appWidth, appHeight, camera));
        stage.addActor(img2);
  }
    
    @Override
 public void render(float delta) {
 
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  batch.begin();
  batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
  batch.end();

  stage.act();
  stage.act(delta);
  stage.draw();
  
  // Also You can get touch input according to your Screen.
  
  if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
   System.out.println(" X " + Gdx.input.getX() * (appWidth / screenWidth));
   System.out.println(" Y " + Gdx.input.getY() * (appHeight / screenHeight));
    }
    
 }
  //
  : 
  :
  //
}
```

run this code in Any type of resolution it will going to adjust in that resolution without any disturbance.

Answer (score 0):

I just think Stage is easy to use.
If there are some wrong,i consider you should check your code:

```
public Actor hit(float x, float y)
```